# Is there any meaning on $\displaystyle\Gamma(i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, gamma-function

Is there any meaning on the $\displaystyle\Gamma(i)$ ?

Comment: Is the any meaning to $\displaystyle\Gamma(x)$ when x is not a positive integer?

Comment: @gauss115 I am not impressed by the quality of your interactions with MSE users until now, to say the least. Please read the comments made to you on previous questions and try to modify your modus operandi.

Comment: Why would he, @did, as he **always** finds someone giving him the complete answer? And there's no much hope this used ever changes his modus operandis: he's asked tens of questions with the same style.

Comment: @DonAntonio That is probably true. What we can do (and what **I** want to do) is to raise the awareness of other users about this sorry state of affairs. In other words, my previous comment was not only, was not primarily, directed at the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, its approximate value is $-0.15494982830181068512 -0.49801566811835604271i$.

The $\Gamma$-function is holomorphic on the whole complex plane, except for simple poles at $0$ and the negative integers.